# Duplicating images

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've been having some trouble with duplicating images... for example i want to duplicate 3 unique pictures but only one comes out. If you could also help me with making the code duplicate 50 across the webpage and make it stop when it reaches 50 lines of images? Thank you here is the code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>RSS Earth Map</title>
<style>
body {
 background-image: url("https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111096/download?f=9k7y8m7if6dkcq345y53s4yp4");
}
img {
 border: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="cDunes">
 <img src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111092/download?f=5xvdsuiuz1khl27tlrkqk9ihy"/>
</div>
<div id="eDunes">
 <img src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf"/>
</div>
<div id="forest>
 <img id="forest src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy"/>
</div>
<div id="oasis">
 <img id="oasis" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi"/>
</div>
<script>
var choose = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);

function createCDunes() {
var cDunes = document.getElementById("cDunes");
var cln = cDunes.cloneNode(true);
document.body.appendChild(cln);
}
function createEDunes() {
var eDunes = document.getElementById("eDunes");
var cln2 = eDunes.cloneNode(true);
document.body.appendChild(cln2);
}
function createForest() {
var oasis = document.getElementById("oasis");
var cln3 = oasis.cloneNode(true);
document.body.appendChild(cln3);
}
for (var line=1; line<60; line++) {
  for(var i=1;i<29;i++) {
 if(choose == 1) {
 createCDunes();
 } else if (choose == 2){
 createEDunes();
 } else {
 createForest();
 }
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you're missing two double quotes here

```
<div id="forest>
    <img id="forest src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy"/>
</div>
```

Second of all, `choose` random variable is being assigned once. You need to move it inside the loop to have:

```
for (var line = 1; line < 60; line++) {
    for (var i = 1; i < 29; i++) {
        var choose = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3));
        if (choose == 1) {
            createCDunes();
        } else if (choose == 2) {
            createEDunes();
        } else {
            createForest();
        }
    }
}
```

also notice I changed the random equation a bit.

*Here is the full snippet:*

```js
function createCDunes() {
  var cDunes = document.getElementById("cDunes");
  var cln = cDunes.cloneNode(true);
  document.body.appendChild(cln);
}

function createEDunes() {
  var eDunes = document.getElementById("eDunes");
  var cln2 = eDunes.cloneNode(true);
  document.body.appendChild(cln2);
}

function createForest() {
  var oasis = document.getElementById("oasis");
  var cln3 = oasis.cloneNode(true);
  document.body.appendChild(cln3);
}
for (var line = 1; line < 60; line++) {
  for (var i = 1; i < 29; i++) {
    var choose = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3));
    if (choose == 1) {
      createCDunes();
    } else if (choose == 2) {
      createEDunes();
    } else {
      createForest();
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111096/download?f=9k7y8m7if6dkcq345y53s4yp4");
}
img {
  border: 0px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="cDunes">
    <img src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111092/download?f=5xvdsuiuz1khl27tlrkqk9ihy" />
  </div>
  <div id="eDunes">
    <img src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf" />
  </div>
  <div id="forest">
    <img id="forest" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy" />

  </div>

  <div id="oasis">
    <img id="oasis" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi" />
  </div>
```

Comment: Is there any way to get the images going left to right? Also how do you get the images to merge?

Comment: Use, just remove the `divs` and give the same ids to the img's themselves.